# Poetry Upgrade Project from Python 3.10.x to Python 3.11.0

Tags: python, upgrade, python-poetry

I have a poetry based Django project using Python 3.10.2. I would like to upgrade the project to use Python 3.11.0.

What is the proper way to do that?

Should I nuke poetry.lock then update the pyproject.toml to

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
```

The ability to easily upgrade to newer versions of Python seems like it should be a core feature but I don't see a command to automate the process.

Comment: try `poetry env use python3.11.0` or the full path to that python version

Comment: I ended up doing this . . .

`pyenv local 3.11.0` 
`poetry env use 3.11.0`
`poetry install`

When I run `poetry env info` I see that the location of the env has been moved out of the standard `$HOME/.cache/pypoetry/...` location and into the project root. It fires up and runs just fine.

Answer (score 3):

try:
`poetry env use python3.11.0`
or the full path to that python version

Answer (score 0):

poetry env use 3.11.0

try with this,woks fine for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).